# How do I make the submenu stay showing so that the user can choose from it?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop sub-menu to the side of the nav bar that is in the middle of the image. I uploaded an image which is a transparent box (representing the bkgd of the sub menu to be)and used the following codes.

When I hover over the nav bar the sub nav shows but then hides after the mouse moves away from the bar. I want the sub menu to stay showing so that the user can choose from it.

The url of my page is:
http://arabic001.com

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#arbNavText01').mouseover(function()  {
                $('#subNav01').show('slow');
            });

            $('#arbNavText01').mouseout(function() {
                $('#subNav01').hide('slow');
            }); 
            })
```

Comment: Can you re-work your posting into a question?  Preferably something clear and concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make the submenu stay showing?

I would say just don't `.hide()` the submenu, but that seems so obvious. Am I missing what you are trying to achieve? You need to be more clear about your question.

Edit: Ok, I took a look at your site and now I know what you mean. But you definitely need to ask your question more clearly.

You should not `.hide()` the submenu when leaving the navigation bar. Instead look for other triggers for hiding the submenu. For example: leaving the submenu, entering another navigation item with the mouse, leaving the navigation bar for more than x seconds without entering the submenu panel.

Comment: Please don't post general comments as an answer!

Comment: When it I deleted it it was more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: lljaas answer is partial. Do you think I need to make my question clearer. lljaas understood my question. But I still don't know what the trigger is supposed to be.

Comment: It depends on what you want. It is clear that you want to make the submenu popup upon entering the navigation item. When do you want it to disappear?

Comment: I want it to disappear after the user clicks on any item on the submenu

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#arbNavText01" ).hover(
    // mouse in
    function() {
      // if the sub menu is not visible
      if ( ! $( "#subNav01" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
        // make it visible
        $( "#subNav01" ).show( "slow" );
      };
    },
    // mouse out
    function() {
      // you can also hide it when mouse is out of "arbNavText01"
      // if not, comment the next 3 lines of code
      if ( $( "#subNav01" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
        $( "#subNav01" ).hide( "slow" );
      };
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried the above code and it is still not doing what I want. The submenu disappears when I move away from the main menu bar.

Comment: I am sorry my last comment was a mistake. When I commented the last three lines of code, the submenu stays, which is a big improvement. Thank you. But now I want it to disappear when I move away from it (the submenu) or when I click on it once it has the items (which will be links).What is the code for that.